# Training and validation accuracy producing overfitting

Tags: deep-learning, model, conv-neural-network, overfitting-underfitting

Below are the code of CNN model, issue is the training accuracy is 96% and validation accuracy is 69%. help me to increase the validation accuracy.

```
`model = Sequential()`
`model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', input_shape=(128,128,1), padding ='same', name='Conv_1'))`
`model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),name='MaxPool_1'))
`model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu',padding ='same', name='Conv_2'))
`model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),name='MaxPool_2'))
`model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding ='same', name='Conv_3'))
`model.add(Flatten(name='Flatten'))`
`model.add(Dropout(0.5,name='Dropout'))
`model.add(Dense(128, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu', name='Dense_1'))
`model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid', name='Dense_2'))`
`model.summary()`

`model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])`

`history = model.fit(x_train2, y_train2, epochs=25, batch_size=10, verbose=2, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))`
```

Findings:
Train: accuracy = 0.937500  ;  loss = 0.125126
Test: accuracy = 0.662508  ;  loss = 1.089228

Answer (score 0):

first, you must try increase the epoch
second, maybe you should try add more the Dense layer before the dense for classification or add Dropout layer after the last Conv2d layer.

I hope you get better